# Is it possible to read a url path variable in a ModelViewSet?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views

Python 3.8, Django 4.0.6, Django Rest Framework 3.13.1: If I am using a DRF ModelViewSet and DefaultRouter like this:

```
# views.py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import MainModel
from .serializers import MainModelSerializer

class MainModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MainModelSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Is there any way here to determine if a lookup_url_kwarg value is provided?
        return queryset.objects.all()
```

```
#urls.py
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'main_models', views.MainModelViewSet, basename='main_models')
urlpatterns = [path('api', include(router.urls)),]
```

is there any way in **MainModelViewSet.get_queryset()** to see if a **lookup_url_kwarg** value is provided and, ideally, what it is? I'm hoping to choose a different serializer depending on whether a specific MainModel instance is requested by ID, and it would be mighty easy to do if I could see if the ID is there. But it looks like Model-based viewsets don't offer any direct way to see that and I might have to examine the path myself, or give up the convenience of **ModelViewSet** and go with some other kind of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can try to read documentation to find the way.
more here: django.views.generic.base.View

On the start of your `ViewSet` the `lookup_key` is saved as attribute in your class, depends on your project:

```
self.request = request # use it if you have lookup in request.POST or request.GET
self.args = args # use it if you have lookup in url as positional argiment
self.kwargs = kwargs # use it if you have lookup in url as named argument
```

after that, if you know your urls.py:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    lookup_url_kwarg_value = self.kwargs.get('my_lookup_url_kwarg_name')
    return queryset.objects.filter(lookup=lookup_url_kwarg_value)
```

Comment: Alas, the error being raised, that made me think this would not be so easy, is **'MainModelViewSet' object has no attribute 'kwargs'**

Comment: i dont know your project and therefore i write three ways: request, args, kwargs. Have you try other?

Comment: I reorganized some of my logic to try **args** and suddenly I stopped getting the error about **kwargs** not existing. I guess I must have had some subtle order-of-operations things going on, where it somehow didn't exist *yet* even though I was referring to it in **get_queryset**; or maybe I had some typo that remained invisible to me for several hours (not impossible, I'm afraid). In any case, I can now see the id (as **pk**) in **kwargs** when added in the routes automatically defined by **DefaultRouter**.